# How to convert ZSH ls timestamps to %Y-%m-%d?

Tags: bash, date, timestamp, zsh, ls

Anyone know how to convert zsh ls timestamps to %Y-%m-%d?

From this (zsh):

```
host1% ls -lrt | tail -1

-rw-r----- 1 user group 4802 Mar 21 15:41 get.csv
```

To this (bash):

```
user@host1:/home/user> ls -ltr | tail -1

-rw-r----- 1 user group 4802 2013-03-21 15:41 get.csv
```

Comment: on bash, does your `ls` alias include `--time-style=long-iso` ? see `type -a ls`

Comment: `ls` is not a shell builtin, it's an external binary, so which shell you run shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can work:

```
$ date -d "Mar 21 15:41" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
2013-03-21 15:41
```

Where with `-d` you give the script the date you want to parse and each variable within `"+ ..."` stands for:

- Y year
- m month
- d day
- H hour (24h)
- M minute

To get `Mar 21 15:41` from the initial line (the one coming from `ls -l`), you can

```
$ echo "-rw-r----- 1 user group 4802 Mar 21 15:41 get.csv" | cut -d' ' -f6,7,8
Mar 21 15:41
```

---

As indicated in comments by the OP, the `-r` (`display the last modification time of FILE`) parameter can be useful for this purpose, as it indicates the file from which we want to know the info:

```
$ date -r name_of_file "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
```

Comment: Yeah that could work and I appreciate the suggestion but I am more looking to do it inline. However you've sparked inspiration, rather than using ls -ltr and awk'ing the date - I'll use

date -r getHostname.sh "+%Y-%m-%d"


Thanks!

Comment: Uhms, I did not know about the `-r` parameter and I think it is great for your purpose. I will update my answer indicating so, to keep it visible for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using GNU ls, you can [specify the time-stamp format as an option to `ls`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Formatting-file-timestamps). Once you figure the format you want you just make an alias to always use that option. Really just check that link and try using the options.